# Is "_symbol" equal to "symbol" in asm?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, kernel

I got that normally `stext` is the entrance of Linux image, but I can only find `_stext` and the `stext` only appears in the `Entry(stext)` which maybe only specifies the entrance but does not show where the symbol is.

So does `stext` equal `_stext`?

Comment: It could be that the `ENTRY` macro decorates `stext` with a leading underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `_symbol` equal to `symbol` in asm?

No. You can see this in the Linux entry point code for Sparc CPUs:

```
_stext:
stext:
```

In this lines, the two symbols `_stext` and `stext` are defined. It would not make sense to define them separately if they were automatically equal.

> only appears in the `Entry(stext)`

Did you check how `Entry()` is defined?

This macro may add an underscore to the name so `Entry(stext)` will expand to:

```
.global _stext
_stext:
```

Comment: I didn't realize `Entry()` can be a Macro and thought it is something like key words.And in my case `Entry()` is defined as 
     `#define ENTRY(name) \
 .globl name ASM_NL \
 ALIGN ASM_NL \
 name:`

Comment: @Yanel: C preprocessor macro names are case-sensitive.  Is there a separate `Entry` macro that does token-pasting to prepend a `_`, or was the macro name actually `ENTRY` the whole time?

Comment: Yes.I found lots of macro definition of `ENTRY`(all uppercase,above is my carelessness).The most of them are defined in other architecture(My question is in  ARM).The rest seems to be common generic.But I cann't find their reference relationship temporarily.
Besides,I found `ENTRY` is defined in GNU LD MANUAL.As vmlinux.lds.S is written by asm and will be compiled as LDS,I guess the one in vmlinux.lds.S will be expanded and disappear in vmlinux.lds as it is compiled.So does the `ALIGN`.But some like `LOADADDR` seems to be defined only in GNU LD MANUAL.Just a guess.